# MongoDB: Replica Set - master vs. slave

Tags: replication, mongodb

We think about moving from a master-slaves to `MongoDB` with `replica-set`.
Now I wonder if `MongoDB` replicas are also set up like `read-only slaves` or if each `mongos` is able to write and sync the others like a master-master farm?

This might reduce the single source of error (`master down`) and also balance the `write-load` for scaling with best performance (not only for read, but also write...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A replica set can only have one primary at any particular time (one master) with the other nodes being secondaries (slaves) and so they are nothing like master-master (i.e. multi-master) replication.

You definitely should move to a replica set from master/slave configuration because that is the preferred and recommended way to replicate.  From MongoDB docs: "replica sets are a functional superset of master/slave, and newer, more robust code".

When a primary fails, one of the secondaries will be automatically elected as a new primary (you can see the docs to see the details of how that happens).

You cannot get write balancing from having a replica set - you can only distribute writes by [sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding) in MongoDB.

Comment: If i understand this correctly, it is only writing with one of the servers within the replica-set, but i do not have to care which one is the master? mongodb master-slaves do manage and failover or sync themselves, really possible? how inconvenient was mysql...

Comment: correct, the drivers keep track of which is primary and send writes to that one (and reads unless you specify slaveOk for the read).  And automatic failover happens as long as the majority of the replica set is up.

Comment: Trying the master slave replication by editing the config seems to work. But how can it automatically failover the master with the "hard-coded", strictly defined master=true/false in the config file on each mongos?

Comment: You need to use proper replica set configuration, not master/slave.   See this page http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Upgrading+to+Replica+Sets#UpgradingtoReplicaSets-UpgradingFromReplicaPairsorMaster%2FSlave

Answer (score 1):

First of all i am not discarding anything of `@Asya Kamsky`. But i would like to write down something about **replica Set : Mater vs Slave**.

As per MongoDB documented source from the **`MongoDB the Definite Guide`** **Master-slave** replication is the most general replication mode supported by `MongoDB`.This mode is very flexible and can be used for `backup`, `failover`, `read scaling`. The basic setup is to start a `master node` and **one or more** `slave nodes`, each of which knows the address of the `master`. To start the `master`, run `mongod --master`. To start a `slave`, run `mongod --slave --source master_address`, where `master_address` is the address of the `master node` that was just started.

Suppose that First, create a directory for the `master` to store data in and choose a `port` (`10000`):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/dbs/master
$ ./mongod --dbpath ~/dbs/master --port 10000 --master
```

Now set up the `slave`, choosing a different data directory and port. For a slave, you also need to tell it who its master is with the `--source` option:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/dbs/slave
$ ./mongod --dbpath ~/dbs/slave --port 10001 --slave --source localhost:10000
```

`All slaves must be replicated from a master node`. There is currently no mechanism for replicating from a slave (**daisy chaining**), because slaves do not keep their **own** `oplog`.

There is no explicit limit on the number of `slaves` in a `cluster`, but having a thousand **slaves** querying a single master will likely overwhelm the **master node**.

> **Note :** If you `slave` off of **two different masters** with the same collections, `MongoDB` will attempt to **merge** them, but correctly doing
>   so is not guaranteed. If you are using a single slave with multiple
>   different masters, it is best to make sure the masters use **different**
>   `namespaces`.

A `replica set` is basically a `master-slave` cluster with automatic `failover`. The biggest difference between a master-slave cluster and a replica set is that a replica set does not have a single master: one is elected by the cluster and may change to another node if the current master goes down. However, they look very similar: a replica set always has a `single master node` (called a **primary**) and one or more slaves (called `secondaries`).

> **Note:** When the primary server goes down, the secondary server will become **`master`**.

The record of operations kept by the **master** is called the **oplog**, short for operation log. The `oplog` is stored in a special database called local, in the **`oplog.$main`** collection. Each document in the `oplog` represents a single operation performed on the **master server**.

In Master-Slave in replica set in **Failover and Primary Election** scenario depends upon the condition and configuration between Master & Slave like that

1. When the `primary` server goes `down`, the `secondary` server will become
   `master`.
2. If the `primary` goes down, the `highest-priority` servers will compare
   how `up-to-date` they are.
3. If the `Primary Server` goes down among the Secondaries the highest-priority `most-up-to-date` `server` will become the `new primary`.

Using `slaves` to **scale** `reads` in `MongoDB` is that replication is `asynchronous`. This means that when data is inserted or updated on the `master`, the data on the `slave` will be `out-of-date` momentarily. This is important to consider if you are serving some requests using queries to `slaves`.

> **Note:** you should be sure never to **`write`** to any database on the **`slave`** that is being `replicated` from the `master`. The `slave` will not
>   revert any such `writes` in order to properly `mirror` the `master`.  The
>   `slave` should also not have any of the databases that are being
>   replicated when it **first starts up**. If it does, those databases will
>   not ever be `fully synced` but will just update with `new operations`.

Comment: Apress and O'Reilly both have books called "The Definitive Guide" which are currently definitively out of date as of February, 2018. The true definitive guide is the online MongoDB manual, which is updated regularly. [Master-Slave Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/master-slave/) pre-dates replica sets and should not be recommended for new deployments or modern versions of MongoDB. Master-Slave replication has been deprecated for components of sharded clusters since MongoDB 3.2 and generally deprecated in the MongoDB 3.6 release.

Comment: The terms `primary` and `secondary` are intentionally used to describe replica set members as these are roles that can change based on elections and auto-failover (as opposed to the fixed roles and manual failover of `master` and `slave` deployments). Replica sets are a significant improvement in integrity, reliability, and support over the legacy Master-Slave replication.

Comment: @Stennie,Yes you are right it's Deprecated since version 3.6: MongoDB 3.6 deprecates the use of master-slave replication. The Replica sets replace "master-slave" replication for most use cases. But the OP has asked about Replica set- master-slave.

Answer (score 0):

It pretty much like "write and sync the others like a master-master farm". as MongoDB docs said "Replica sets are a form of asynchronous master/slave replication, adding automatic failover and automatic recovery of member nodes." Please check http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets